# Кодировка при чтении файла

Tags: python

Я написал программу на Python, которая выполняет чтение из тестового файла и выводит содержимое в консоль, но когда содержимое выводится, выводятся непонятные символы, что делать?

Comment: Что за файл, в какой кодировке файл, в какой консоли, мы гадать должны?

Comment: При **открытии** файла укажите параметр `encoding="utf-8"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы читать файл в нужной вам кодировке, нужно указать ее, скорее всего это `utf-8`

```
file = open("text.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло

Comment: @DefaulDima вы можете поставить галочку и нажать кнопку "Ответ полезен"